# Replacing a number followed by a colon with just the number and a comma

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a number followed by a colon (":") with the number followed by a comma.

- These occurrences should be only at the beginning of the record, not elsewhere.

File called test_01.csv looks like this:

```
3:Item A,,"100.00",
5:Item B,,"-200.95",
4:Item C,,"-300.75",
2:Item D,,"400.92",
100:Item E,,"600.91",
10245:Item F,,"750.01",
ITEM G, 1395,,"898.98",
ITEM H, 34561,,"765.01",9999999:
3:Item A,,"100.00",999999:
```

I would like to have it look like this:
(Notice, the colon (":") has been replaced by a comma)

```
3,Item A,,"100.00",
5,Item B,,"-200.95",
4,Item C,,"-300.75",
2,Item D,,"400.92",
100,Item E,,"600.91",
10245,Item F,,"750.01",
ITEM G, 1395,,"898.98",
ITEM H, 34561,,"765.01",9999999: 
3,Item A,,"100.00",999999:
```

Note: The last two records have instances of a number followed by colon in positions that are not necessarily at the beginning of the record, which should be left intact.

I have tried:

```
sed 's/^(\d+)(\:)/$1\,/g' test_01.csv
```

which results in no change.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "all occurrences" is ambiguous. You seem to only want occurrences at the start of line to be changed

Comment: GNU sed (if it is yours) does not interpret `\d` as a digit, use `[[:digit:]]`. If you want to use parentheses and `+`, you need the `-E` option, else use `\(...\)` and `\+`. There is no need to parenthesise or escape the colon. The back-references are `\N`, not `$N`. And using the `g` global replacement does not really make sense if you anchor your regex to the beginning of line (`^`). Do you want to replace all colons following a number, or only the first? If all remove the `^`, if the first, remove the `g`.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the brackets and the plus sign, use `[0–9]` (sed doesn’t know about `\d`) and use `\1` instead of `$1`:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\):/\1,/' test_01.csv
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/S4OLv0).

Note: No need to escape or capture colon, or to use global flag `g` since there can only be at most one match due to the start of line anchor `^`.

Comment: After reviewing the above responses, I was able to arrive at the following: /   `sed 's/\(^[0-9]\+\):/\1,/' test_01.csv` \ which "seems" to work. \ - please note I did provide a more representative example relative to the original question than the original example.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I was trying to simplify, but start of line added and demo link updated.